# Solving an Attribute Error found while installing or building on Google Cloud Platform

Tags: python, gcloud

So I have python version 3.8.12, and while trying to build a cloudrun app, I get the error:

```
ERROR: gcloud failed to load: module 'collections' has no attribute 'Mapping'
```

Now when I try to run and install Gcloud SDK again, I get the error:

```
Welcome to the Google Cloud SDK! Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/Users/eshanchatty/downloads/./google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/install.py", line 12, in <module>
    import bootstrapping   File "/Users/eshanchatty/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/bootstrapping.py", line 46, in <module>
    from googlecloudsdk.core.updater import update_manager   File "/Users/eshanchatty/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/updater/update_manager.py", line 39, in <module>
    from googlecloudsdk.core.console import progress_tracker   File "/Users/eshanchatty/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/console/progress_tracker.py", line 651, in <module>
    class _BaseStagedProgressTracker(collections.Mapping): AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'Mapping'
```

What is causing this, and how can I solve this?

Comment: Your issue appears to related to [this](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-python/pull/419) but it's unclear why you're experiencing it with 3.8.12 as [collections.Mapping](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html) should be preserved until 3.9.

Answer (score 22):

Yesterday I updated Fedora to version 35. This version uses Python 3.10 by default.

In this version, *collections* does not have *Mapping*. I got the same errors as you did.

I haven't tried to reinstall Google Cloud SDK. Instead, I wrote this line to my `~/.bashrc` file:

```
export CLOUDSDK_PYTHON=python2
```

Then closed and opened the terminal.

Now the SDK uses Python 2 instead of Python 3. This solved the issue for me.

Comment: A `set -Ux CLOUDSDK_PYTHON python2` solved it for me in Fish.

Comment: On Debian 11, which also has python 10.0 installed, I use `export CLOUDSDK_PYTHON=python3.9` and it worked for me

Comment: Amazing that they still haven't fixed this? At least fix the error message to say "... is the path to a working Python 2.7 or 3.5-3.9 executable (my gcloud version is 334.0.0-0)

Comment: Another take is that distributing python programs is a PITA..

Answer (score -1):

I used this doc to fix my python on macos, eventually after fixing python the issue got resolved.

https://gist.github.com/MuhsinFatih/ee0154199803babb449b5bb98d3475f7

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31229168)